# Keep different install directory on choco upgrade

Tags: firefox, chocolatey

I've installed Firefox using Chocolatey to the different install directory `C:\Software\Firefox` with the following command: `choco install firefox --params "/InstallDir:C:\Software\Firefox"`

When upgrading Firefox via `choco upgrade firefox`, the Firefox installation gets moved from `C:\Software\Firefox` to the Firefox default `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox`.

Can I somehow work around this behavior so that my custom install directory gets preserved even on `choco upgrade`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable the Chocolatey feature `useRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades` with the following command:

```
choco feature enable --name=useRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades
```

After this, the install directory was preserved even when calling `choco upgrade`.